# How to connect to multiple VPNs using "solace-jms-spring-boot" API

Tags: spring-boot, jms, solace

I was successfully able to implement Spring-boot application to connect to a single VPN and consume/produce messages from/to the queue on that VPN using instructions provided here (very helpful):
https://github.com/SolaceProducts/solace-jms-spring-boot

But now I am struggling with the following problem:
As per read me, with this property we can only specify one VPN: solace.jms.msgVpn

How to connect to 2 different VPNs and consume/produce from/to queues in each VPN? Can we do this in same spring boot app?

Any help will be much appreciated.

Another question - How do we acknowledge the message back using these API?

Answer (score 0):

Although you cannot currently use `solace-jms-spring-boot` to connect to more than one VPN at a time, you have a couple of options:

1. Publish back to the same VPN on a different topic, and have that bridged to another VPN using a VPN bridge.  The advantage of this approach is that you can bridge to a number of other VPNs if needed, which can be located on the same or another broker.  Since this is done administratively, there are no changes required to the application other than publishing to a new topic.  Note that that you will need to configure the bridge(s) and subscription(s), which requires administrative access.  If you use the new Dynamic Message Routing feature, you could reduce or eliminate the administrative burden associated with configuring topics.  DMR works across multiple sites and dynamically handles the routing of messages as subscriptions get added or removed.
2. Use the Solace Spring Cloud Stream (SCS) binder (available on GitHub and Maven Central) in your Spring Boot app.  The binder supports multiple binders in the same app using the same or different transport - in this case, you can define two Solace binders to the same broker but with different VPN names.

Regarding acking messages, with `solace-jms-spring-boot` you don't need to explicitly ack messages as local transactions are used by Spring JMS.  If your callback throws an exception, the transaction is rolled back, otherwise it's committed.  If it gets rolled back, by default the message will go back onto the queue and get redelivered.  This could cause your app to go into an infinite loop trying to process a bad message, so it's recommended to set the property `max-redelivery` > 0 on the queue, and also designate a dead message queue where the poison message will go after exceeding the redelivery limit.  By default, the DMQ is `#DEAD_MSG_QUEUE`, which you may need to create.  Note that the message must also be published with the DMQ eligible flag set to true.

If you decide to use the SCS binder instead, the acking mechanism is different and does not use local transactions, but instead is managed by SCS.  Details on retries, DMQs (also known as DLQs), and global and app-level error handlers can be found on in the SCS reference documentation.  Since SCS provides similar functionality, you don't need to configure max-redelivery or the DMQ on the broker, and the message does not need to have the DMQ eligible flag set.  Instead, you will need to configure error handling in your app properties / YAML.  In general, when your app throws an exception, redelivery will be attempted, and after exceeding the delivery limit (3 times by default), it will either go to a DLQ or an error handler defined at the app or global level.  As noted earlier, how this occurs will depend on your configuration.

An example of disabling local transactions is [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-messaging.html).  You can then use `setSessionAcknowledgeMode(Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE)` to enable client acks. However, any exceptions may not roll back other operations (e.g. if you publish a reply on another session).  Note that your `@JmsListener` annotation should specify the `containerFactory` argument referencing your container factory.

As per the docs noted for `DefaultMessageListenerContainer` it's best to use transactions if you want to avoid message loss or non-atomic operations.  Both transactions and client acks are completed when your callback returns successfully.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I used the workaround to initialize SolConnectionFactory in my getDefJmsListenerFactory() method and set the VPN and other connection properties manually.

Comment: SolConnectionFactory scf = SolJmsUtility.createConnectionFactory();
scf.setVPN(env.getProperty("vpn.name"));
factory.setConnectionFactory(scf);

Comment: Regarding the message acknowledgement, you mentioned that Spring uses local transactions. So if I set the factory.setSessionTransacted(false); will it still acknowledge the message to router?

Comment: Please see new details added to address your question re: no transactions.

Answer (score 0):

This is like this in almost all spring-boot components: they support only one connection with the auto-configuration but custom configurations are still possible.

Note, this is not a Solace limitation, for example: it is the same situation with the Spring-Boot ActiveMQ `spring-boot-starter-activemq` where you need to define specific Beans for each connection (see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73980758/628006)).

I had a similar need to create dynamically a JmsTemplate depending from the user connected and here follows an example with dynamic vpn, user and password (client credentials):

```java
// Create a SolConnectionFactory dynamically with vpn and client credentials.
private SolConnectionFactory getSolConnectionFactory(String vpn, String userName, String password, ) {
    try {
        Hashtable<String, String> ht = new Hashtable<>(6);
        JMSProperties props = new JMSProperties(ht);
        props.initialize();
        SolConnectionFactoryImpl cf = new SolConnectionFactoryImpl(props);
        cf.setHost(solaceProperties.messagingApi().brokerUrl());
        cf.setVPN(vpn);
        cf.setUsername(userName);
        cf.setPassword(password);
        cf.setDirectTransport(true);
        return cf;
    } catch (Exception exc) {
        LOGGER.error("Exception found during Solace Connection Factory creation.", exc);
        throw new IllegalStateException("Unable to create Solace connection factory, ensure that the sol-jms-jakarta-<version>.jar is the classpath", exc);
        }
    }

// Create a dedicated JMSTemplate with dynmamic vpn and client credentials.
private JmsTemplate createJmsTemplate(String vpn, String username, String password) {
    JmsTemplate jmsTemplate = new JmsTemplate(getSolConnectionFactory(vpn, username, password));
    CachingConnectionFactory ccf = new CachingConnectionFactory();
    ccf.setTargetConnectionFactory(jmsTemplate.getConnectionFactory());
    jmsTemplate.setConnectionFactory(ccf);
    return jmsTemplate;
}
```

You can also define qualified Beans for the `JmsTemplate` (with e.g. `@Bean(name="sol-conn-vpn-1")` if you have a static number of VPN's or just calling the createJmsTemplate method from your service bean whenever you need.